# Spectral theory for compact normal operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators, normal-operator

Let $T$ be a compact normal operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H.$ Then I came across the fact that the spectrum $\sigma (T)$ of $T$ is either finite or countably infinite containing $0.$ I have seen the following claims in the lecture note I am following.

$(1)$ Let $\sigma (T) = \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_k\} \cup \{0\}.$ Let $\mathfrak h_j = \text {ker} (T - \lambda_jI),\ $ $1 \leq j \leq k.$ Let $P_j$ be the projection onto $\mathfrak h_j.$ Let $T_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i P_i.$

$$\color {red} {\text {Then}\ \sigma(T-T_k) = \{0\}.}$$

$(2)$ If $\sigma (T)$ is countably infinite then write $$\sigma(T) = \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \cdots \} \cup \{0\}.$$

$$\color{red} {\text {Then}\ \sigma (T - T_n) = \{\lambda_{n+1}, \lambda_{n+2}, \cdots \} \cup \{0\},\ \text {for all}\ n \geq 1.}$$

Can anybody make the statements in red clear to me? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you know about Spectral Theory of (normal) compact operators? Do you know/did you prove that aside from 0 the elements in the spectrum are Eigenvalues of finite multiplicity?

Comment: @J. Becker I know that. If there exists such a $0 \neq \lambda \in \sigma (T)$ then we can find out an ONS for the underlying Hilbert space such that image of any two distinct terms of the ONS under $T$ is $\sqrt 2 \left \lvert \lambda \right \rvert$ distance away from each other. Hence the image will have no convergent subsequence which contradicts the fact that $T$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

The statements are immediate consequences of what is known as the spectral theorem in its compact, normal version. Conway's book is the place to look for this theorem.

> **Theorem** (spectral theorem, normal, compact version)
>
> Let $T$ be a compact, normal operator in $\mathbb{B}(H)$. Then $T$ has at most countably many distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_n\}$ and if they are countably many then $\lambda_n\to0$. If $P_n$ denotes the projection onto the eigenspace $\ker(T-\lambda_n I)$, then the projections $\{P_n\}$ are pairwise orthogonal and
> $$T=\sum_n\lambda_nP_n$$
> in the sense that
> $$\|T-\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_nP_n\|_{\mathbb{B}(H)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0. $$

The claims follow directly from this theorem. (1) follows trivially and for (2) note that $T-T_n=\sum_{k\geq n+1}\lambda_kP_k$, so $T-T_n$ is a compact, normal operator and its only eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=n+1}^\infty$, thus $\sigma(T-T_n)=\{\lambda_k\}_{k=n+1}^\infty\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Our instructor actually tries to prove the spectral theorem for compact normal operators using the observations I asked as questions.